# why i cant redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

what is the problem about this code?
it create session correctly but dont redirect me, there is no "echo" before "header".

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        include('../maincore/connect-db.php');
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supporter WHERE username='$username'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $pass=$row['password'];

        if($password==$pass && $password!=''){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['name']=$row['name'];
            $_SESSION['family']=$row['family'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            $_SESSION['type']=$row['type'];
            header('location: works.php');
        }else{
            header('location: index.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get some error from your mysql?

Comment: And as always be very cautious about SQL injection

Comment: no, it connects and checks password and create session...

Answer (score 0):

If this is your real code, shouldn't you be using sha1 or some sort of irreversible hashing for your passwords? Just.. wondering..

Just tried your code, things are working fine on my end.. so you have to give us more info on your error logs

Comment: sha1, sha256, php's crypt.. anything but plain-text..my idea was to point him to the direction of hashing passwords, and obviously it gets long from there, adding salt, disabling apache gzip etc etc.. that's totally a different topic.

Comment: I can see that, what I mean is, you should definitely be using some form of encryption or hashing to secure your passwords. Don't leave them in plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message

The document headers should be send before the document content.

PHP executes at real time, when I request a page the page isn't evaluated and sent so when you write the documment starts to send teh documment and no more headers can be added to the transfer.

Your problem is than you echo something before the header.

Error examples:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Send the session id header.
    echo "This is a rawr text"; // Print something to the document
    header("location: index.php"); // And this line will throw a error cause you already writed in the document.
?>
```

Another error:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<body>
Inside of body
</body>
<?php
    header("location: index.php"); // this will throw a error cause the text upside has been already sent.
?>
```

Solution:
Put your code (**header()** functions) before write in the document.